# mysql parse error shows when query has 3 conditions

Tags: javascript, mysql

i have a select query to a local database and for some reason the following error shows up:

```
 ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM site WHERE name = OCC AND date_start = 2018-07-30 08:00:00 AND date_end = '' at line 1
```

here's my query:

```
connection.query("SELECT *, FROM shop WHERE name = "  + shop_name + " AND date_start = " + myDate +  " AND date_end = " + myDate2, function (err, result) 
    {
        if (err) 
        {
            console.log("Error Is:" + err);
        } 
        else 
        {
            console.log('DATA EXISTING IS =' + JSON.stringify(result));
        }
    });
```

am i missing something?

Comment: The comma `SELECT *,` is a syntax error.

Comment: above + and add single quotes like `name = '"  + shop_name + "'`. Also I would recommend using a parametrised query as this can be subjected to SQL injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual mantra: use parameterized queries. They will prevent SQL injections and make your service more secure. Furthermore they will take care of the usual pitfalls when building a query using string concatenation.

Let's have a look at your query

```
"SELECT *, FROM shop WHERE name = " + shop_name + " AND date_start = " + myDate + " AND date_end = " + myDate2
```

Which spells out to something like

```
SELECT *, FROM shop WHERE name = myshop AND date_start = 2018-07-30 AND date_end = 2018-08-10
```

There are at least 3 errors

1. The `,` behind the `SELECT *` this is also the one the error tells you about. I suppose you had a column list and replaced it with *
2. The shop `name` column is most certainly some char column. So you have to enclose your values with quotes
3. Also the dates must be used with quotes, so the SQL engine will parse it to a date and do the comparison. For some SQL engines there is also a special annotation for dates. Have a look in the documentation.

This query should work

```
 "SELECT * FROM shop WHERE name = '" + shop_name + "' AND date_start = '" + myDate + "' AND date_end = '" + myDate2 +"'"
```

depending on what `myDate` and `myDate2` are.

At least problems 2 and 3 would not happen if you use parameterized queries. Consult the documentation of the library you are using.